# Saving a text file with an unknown extension

Tags: export

I need to export a file with the extension .mac (short for macro in an external program), though it is essentially a text file (saving .mac in Microsoft notepad works fine).  However if I try something like:

```
Export["test.mac", "The brown fox."]
```

I recieve the error:

```
Export::infer: Cannot infer format of file test.mac. >>
```

Is there a workaround?

Comment: `Export["test.mac", "The brown fox.", "Table"]` is ok? Or other, take a look at `Deatils` section for `Export`.

Comment: @Kuba Yes, that did it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Export` takes a third argument that specifies [the format](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ImportingAndExporting.html):

```
Export["test.mac", "The brown fox.", "Text"]

Import["/tmp/test.mac", "Text"]
(* "The brown fox." *)
```